# Simulate Lens flare and chromatic aberration using python

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0, scikit-image

I have a set of images. I have to use them for training a network. I want to simulate a lens flare effect and chromatic aberration on the images. I have tried to find some function in OpenCV, scikit and other python image library but no help from there. How can i simulate these effect on my image? Rough idea or code will be useful. Images are in jpg format.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what kind of lens flare you are trying to achieve. Create e.g. hexagon mask and overlay multiple instances of it partially transparently between start and end point of the flare axis? Hexagons should be at least slightly bigger "in sun's direction" and spaced more or less in equal distance compared to each others. User should be able to click start and end points of said axis from the pic and use e.g. mouse to rotate, zoom in/out the axis and define number of flare elements to be added.

Answer (score 0):

For chromatic aberration, I would split the RGB components, apply slightly different scaling factors, and merge back. Depending on whether you want to simulate a flint or crown effect, the factors will be increasing or decreasing.